# I can't package my py file to an exe file

Tags: python, pygame, exe, pyinstaller

I'm very new to programming, and I decided to use python as my first programming language! So I have created a game through Pygame that has no additional files, it is only a single python file.

It's just a quiz game, and I have created a GUI through the code itself. The game runs just fine when using cmd to run the game, but when I turn it into an executable using pyinstaller and try running it, it will just flash an empty windowed black screen, then close. I even tried using cx freeze. I tried so many solutions but none of them worked. Any help would be appreciated. I'm very new to programming so If you can answer my question, can you please explain it in beginner words hahaha. Here is the code for my game:

```py
import random 
from random import randint

WIDTH = 1280

HEIGHT = 720

def draw():
    screen.fill("green yellow")
    screen.draw.filled_rect(main_box, "sky blue")
    screen.draw.filled_rect(timer_box, "sky blue")
    screen.draw.text("Score: " + str(score), color="black", topleft=(10, 10))

    for box in answer_boxes:
        screen.draw.filled_rect(box, "orange")

    screen.draw.textbox(str(time_left), timer_box, color=('black'))
    screen.draw.textbox(question[0], main_box, color=('black'))

    index = 1
    for box in answer_boxes:
        screen.draw.textbox(question[index], box, color=('black'))
        index = index + 1

def game_over():
    global question, time_left, scoredecreaserps
    scoredecreaserps = 0
    message = 'Game Over. You got %s questions correct' %str(numques)
    question = [message, '-', '-', '-', '-', 5]
    time_left = 0

def correct_answer():
    global question, score, numques, time_left

    numques = numques + 1
    score = score + 1000

    if questions:
        question = questions.pop()
        time_left = 10
    else:
        print('End of questions')
        game_over()

def on_mouse_down(pos):
    index = 1

    for box in answer_boxes:

        if box.collidepoint(pos):
            print('Clicked on answer' + str(index))

            if index == question[5]:
                print('You got it correct!')
                correct_answer()
            else:
                game_over()

        index = index + 1

def update_time_left():
    global time_left

    if time_left:
        time_left = time_left - 1
    else:
        game_over()

def score_lower():
    global score

    if score:
        score = score - scoredecreaserps

main_box = Rect(50, 40, 820, 240)
timer_box = Rect(990, 40, 240, 240)

answer_box1 = Rect(50, 358, 495, 165)
answer_box2 = Rect(735, 358, 495, 165)
answer_box3 = Rect(50, 538, 495, 165)
answer_box4 = Rect(735, 538, 495, 165)

answer_boxes = [answer_box1, answer_box2, answer_box3, answer_box4]

scoredecreaserps = 80
numques = 0
score = 0
time_left = 10

q1 = ["Who was the third president of the Philippines?",
      'Rodrigo Duterte', 'Ramon Magsaysay', 'Jose P. Laurel',
      'Fidel V. Ramos', 3]

q2 = ['When was the Philippines granted independece from the US?'
      , '1977', '1946', '1935', '1907', 2]

q3 = ['When was the Philippines colonized by Spain', '1898', '1523', '1654',
      '1521', 4]

questions = [q1, q2, q3]

random.shuffle(questions)

question = questions.pop(0)
clock.schedule_interval(update_time_left, 1.0)
clock.schedule_interval(score_lower, 1.0)
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to include in your code all necessary imports? So that code can be run just straight away without any dependencies or modifications. So that we can reproduce problem on our machines and try to solve it.

Comment: Try running `pyinstaller` with these options `--noupx --onefile`, no upx option is very important, otherwise pyinstaller often creates damaged dlls after re-compression.

Comment: I have tried what you said, on running pyinstaller with --noupx --onefile. It still didn't work, but unlike before, it actually showed me an error. But the window closes super quickly so I don't have enough time to read it. I think It started with 'Traceback'.

Comment: Then probably I think I solved your problem with pyinstaller packaging, if you see traceback then it means now error is inside the code, not in packaging program, so it is a diffrerent issue now. You can make a global `try/except` block for whole program so that you catch your exception and print it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand what you mean with including all the necessary imports. Im very new to this, so I don't really understand it. Do you mean for example, 'import random'. Do I have to import more imports just like I did with 'random'

Comment: No, you need to surround your whole code with a `try except` block. Check this link to get a better understanding on `try except` https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Comment: So I tried running the program through opening cmd and typing 'pgzrun' and then the file. The program works perfectly

Comment: ok, I will try using try except.

Comment: By including all imports I mean that if your whole working program is not to large then include all of it source code here, if it is not a secret. It will allow us to run it on our machines and provide better help to you. If whole program is too large then don't include it. Because right now this program when I run gives me many errors.

Comment: Wow! I undertstood, you need to install `python -m pip install pgzero` and then `pgzrun script.py`.

Comment: I've just managed to package your script, installed `faulthandler` module and catched exception in your code, [here is an exception screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OraBK.png) , seems like there is some crash inside dll or something similar.

Comment: Hooray! I've managed to solve your task at least on my Windows machine, [here is my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64612877/941531). 5-6 improvements were needed to achieve task.

Comment: @ParulDeepSingh Our discussion has been moved to [this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223904/discussion-on-answer-by-arty-i-cant-package-my-py-file-to-an-exe-file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve your task, do next steps:

1. Necessary modules need to be installed one time:

```
python -m pip install pyinstaller pgzero requests
```

2. Retrieve archive `game.zip` with all needed resources by running next command line:

```
python -c "import requests, base64; f = open('game.zip', 'wb'); f.write(base64.b64decode(requests.get('https://pastebin.com/raw/GnJ72zgP').content)); f.close()"
```

3. Inside `game.zip` file there's already everything needed, just run `package.cmd` there and after packaging taking some time you'll get resulting exe file in `dist/script.exe`.
4. `game.zip` has next files:

   - `package.cmd` contains one line `pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --noupx --add-data "./pgzero/;./pgzero/" --add-data "./fonts/;./fonts/" --runtime-tmpdir "c:/temp/" script.py`
   - `script.py` contains full script code that I'll provide down below.
   - `fonts/arial.ttf` contains file taken from `C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf`.
   - `pgzero/data/` equals to folder `D:\bin2\Python37\Lib\site-packages\pgzero\data\` (in this path change location of your Python distribution).

Full corrected and improved script code is down below. You may need to change first lines - variable `logname` equals to path were to write logs, all exceptions are written there if you program crashes, variable `fontname` equals to file name of font that is located inside `./fonts/arial.ttf` in `game.zip`, you may replace this font with one you like.

Script can be run both by `python script.py` command or by packaging it into `script.exe` using `pyinstaller`.

Next improvements were made:

1. Added `try`/`except` global block in order to catch all program's exceptions/errors, inside `except` block errors are saved to log file with path from `logname` variable.
2. Added `faulthandler` in first lines of script in order to catch all critical errors like `Segmentation Fault`.
3. Added `os.chdir(...)` in first lines to change working directory to one that packaged script is runned from. Because by default packaged script working directory is not equal to directory were script is located.
4. Added `import pgzrun` in first lines and `pgzrun.go()` in last lines, this allows script to be runnable just by `python script.py` instead of command line `pgzrun script.py` which is common for `pygame` scripts running. This improvement was necessary in order to allow easy packaging using pyinstaller.
5. Added `fontname = fontname` argument to all calls of `screen.draw.text...(...)` functions, because packaged script was crashing if font file name was not given.

```
try:
    logname = 'c:/temp/pgzrun.log'
    fontname = 'arial.ttf'

    import faulthandler
    faulthandler.enable()
    
    import os, sys
    
    script_dir = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    os.chdir(script_dir)
    
    import pgzrun
    
    import random 
    from random import randint

    WIDTH = 1280
    HEIGHT = 720

    def draw():
        screen.fill("green yellow")
        screen.draw.filled_rect(main_box, "sky blue")
        screen.draw.filled_rect(timer_box, "sky blue")
        screen.draw.text("Score: " + str(score), color="black", topleft=(10, 10), fontname=fontname)

        for box in answer_boxes:
            screen.draw.filled_rect(box, "orange")

        screen.draw.textbox(str(time_left), timer_box, color=('black'), fontname=fontname)
        screen.draw.textbox(question[0], main_box, color=('black'), fontname=fontname)

        index = 1
        for box in answer_boxes:
            screen.draw.textbox(question[index], box, color=('black'), fontname=fontname)
            index = index + 1

    def game_over():
        global question, time_left, scoredecreaserps
        scoredecreaserps = 0
        message = 'Game Over. You got %s questions correct' %str(numques)
        question = [message, '-', '-', '-', '-', 5]
        time_left = 0

    def correct_answer():
        global question, score, numques, time_left

        numques = numques + 1
        score = score + 1000

        if questions:
            question = questions.pop()
            time_left = 10
        else:
            print('End of questions')
            game_over()

    def on_mouse_down(pos):
        index = 1

        for box in answer_boxes:

            if box.collidepoint(pos):
                print('Clicked on answer' + str(index))

                if index == question[5]:
                    print('You got it correct!')
                    correct_answer()
                else:
                    game_over()

            index = index + 1

    def update_time_left():
        global time_left

        if time_left:
            time_left = time_left - 1
        else:
            game_over()

    def score_lower():
        global score

        if score:
            score = score - scoredecreaserps

    main_box = Rect(50, 40, 820, 240)
    timer_box = Rect(990, 40, 240, 240)

    answer_box1 = Rect(50, 358, 495, 165)
    answer_box2 = Rect(735, 358, 495, 165)
    answer_box3 = Rect(50, 538, 495, 165)
    answer_box4 = Rect(735, 538, 495, 165)

    answer_boxes = [answer_box1, answer_box2, answer_box3, answer_box4]

    scoredecreaserps = 80
    numques = 0
    score = 0
    time_left = 10

    q1 = ["Who was the third president of the Philippines?",
          'Rodrigo Duterte', 'Ramon Magsaysay', 'Jose P. Laurel',
          'Fidel V. Ramos', 3]

    q2 = ['When was the Philippines granted independece from the US?'
          , '1977', '1946', '1935', '1907', 2]

    q3 = ['When was the Philippines colonized by Spain', '1898', '1523', '1654',
          '1521', 4]

    questions = [q1, q2, q3]

    random.shuffle(questions)

    question = questions.pop(0)
    clock.schedule_interval(update_time_left, 1.0)
    clock.schedule_interval(score_lower, 1.0)

    pgzrun.go()
        
except:
    import traceback
    with open(logname, 'a', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        f.write(''.join(traceback.format_exc()) + '\n')
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223904/discussion-on-answer-by-arty-i-cant-package-my-py-file-to-an-exe-file).

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Programming, you should not focus on creating binaries. Learn how to run your apps in the shell and develop a bit your Developer skills by learning Object-Oriented Programming, Functional programming, pros, and cons of each code approach.

You will realize that most of your projects will not require an exe to run it. If you want a file to click and run, you can run the python file directly with some Windows configuration*, or create a shell script for it to set up and/or run. This approach is a more natural way to use python.

* I don't use Windows in a long time, but I believe that you can open a python file with python.exe from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I use in such cases auto-py-to-exe
https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

My System: Python 2.7 on Windows 8.1
People tell me that the exe works also good
with Linux + Wine

Comment: I have tried this also, but unfortunately, this does not work :(